# Improving the speed

Tags: julia

Here is my code in Julia and I would like to improve its speed since it is slow for large dataset. I provided the code with a small example so it can be executed and produce the results. I think that bottleneck is using find function in the loop which causes the code to be very slow but I don't know how I can replace it with sth faster.

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [4,7,8,9], [9,10], [2,3,4,5]]

mx = maximum(maximum(ar))

idx_new = zeros(Int, mx)

flag = ones(Int, mx);

Hscore = rand(1, length(A))

thresh = 0.2 * sum(Hscore)

acc_q = 0

pos = sortperm(vec(Hscore))

iter = 1

while acc_q < thresh

        acc_q = acc_q + Hscore[pos[iter]]

        nd = A[pos[iter]]

        fd_flag = flag[nd]

        cc = in.(fd_flag, 2)

        node = nd[findall(x->x==0, cc)]

        dd = nd[findall(x->x!=0, cc)]

        TF = isempty(dd)

        if TF == true

            q_val = Hscore[pos[iter]]

            acc_q = acc_q + q_val

            idx_new[vec(node)] .= (val + 1)

            flag[node] .= 2

            val = val + 1;

            iter = iter + 1

        end # end of if TF

    end ## end of while loop
```

Comment: Also, frame your code in a function. In this way variables will no longer be global and the compiler can do a much metter job!!

Answer (score 0):

While "please improve my code" is not a right question style for StackOverflow, generally when searching many times for element among many many options these are the first two that you might consider:

1. Sort the list of elements (with `sort!`) and use `searchsorted` to find the desired element
2. Use `Set(mylist)` to create a hash set and than search within the set.